# configure: error: Package requirements(...) were not met

Tags: package-management, unity-greeter, autotools, automake

I am trying to make some tweaks to Unity Greeter. So I fetched the source code from launchpad.net. The package came with no makefile. After a bit of googling, I found they use autotools project structure. When I used automake tool to create the make file for the project, I got an error.

```
/usr/bin/gnome-autogen.sh checking for automake >= 1.7...   testing automake... found 1.15 checking for autoreconf >= 2.53...   testing autoreconf... found 2.69 checking for intltool >= 0.25...   testing intltoolize... found 0.51.0 checking for pkg-config >= 0.14.0...   testing pkg-config... found 0.29.1 checking for gnome-common >=
2.3.0...   testing gnome-doc-common... found 3.14.0 Checking for required M4 macros...
**Warning**: I am going to run `configure' with no arguments. If you wish to pass any to it, please specify them on the `./autogen.sh' command line.

Processing ./configure.ac Running gnome-doc-common... Running intltoolize... Running autoreconf... autoreconf: Entering directory `.' autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext autoreconf: running: aclocal --force --warnings=no-portability  autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force --warnings=no-portability autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
--warnings=no-portability autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing --warnings=no-portability tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/flat-button.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility. automake: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects' automake: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output automake: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However, automake: this behaviour will change in future Automake versions: they will automake: unconditionally cause object files to be placed in the same subdirectory automake: of the corresponding sources. automake: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your automake: project, to avoid future incompatibilities. tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/toggle-box.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/user-list.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/greeter-list.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/remote-login-service.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/background.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/email-autocompleter.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/cairo-utils.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/animate-timer.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/fadable.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/fadable-box.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/dash-box.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/user-prompt-box.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/fading-label.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/cached-image.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/dash-entry.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/dash-button.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/prompt-box.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/session-list.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/main-window.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/list-stack.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/settings.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled tests/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '../src/shutdown-dialog.c' is in a subdirectory, tests/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled autoreconf: Leaving directory `.' Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode ... checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c checking whether build environment is sane... yes checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p checking for gawk... gawk checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes checking whether make supports nested variables... yes checking for style of include used by make... GNU checking for gcc... gcc checking whether the C compiler works... yes checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out checking for suffix of executables...  checking whether we are cross compiling... no checking for suffix of object files... o checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3 checking for valac... valac configure: WARNING: no proper vala compiler found configure: WARNING: you will not be able to compile vala source files checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes ./configure: line 3706: GLIB_GSETTINGS: command not found checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes checking for UNITY_GREETER... no configure: error: Package requirements (
    gtk+-3.0
    gdk-x11-3.0
    indicator3-0.4
    libido3-0.1 >= 13.10.0
    liblightdm-gobject-1 >= 1.12.0
    freetype2
    cairo-ft
    libcanberra
    pixman-1
    x11
    xext ) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found No package 'gdk-x11-3.0' found No package 'indicator3-0.4' found No package 'libido3-0.1' found No package 'liblightdm-gobject-1' found No package 'freetype2' found No package 'cairo-ft' found No package 'libcanberra' found No package 'pixman-1' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables UNITY_GREETER_CFLAGS and UNITY_GREETER_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I'm not able to figure out how to solve this error. I tried to install those packages from repository with apt. I am using **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit**.

I posted the same question in StackOverflow and got no responses. I hope I will found some Ubuntu enthusiasts here !

Comment: What packages did you try to install, exactly? you will need the `-dev` packages for each of the missing components i.e. `libgtk-3-dev` and so on

Comment: It worked but got into another problem : (